# New MOBO + old Harddrive = NO BOOT

Tags: windows-xp, boot, motherboard, reboot

My old mobo died, i bought a new one and swapped it. Plugged my old Harddrive and fired it up. I get a POST screen, the Windows logo ... and then the system restarts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had this problem. I suspected it was due to either Windows licencing (Windows does not like it if your hardware has changed drastically) or, more probably, wrong drivers. I suspected the latter because it was crashing, instead of giving me an error.

I fixed it by re-installing Windows.

What i suggest is to backup all your important files, and re-install Windows.

Comment: Windows considers a new motherboard to be a new machine - it's even mentioned in one of their microsoftillion FAQs.

Comment: Yes, but I would have just assumed that it would give you some kinda of activation error (but I still wouldn't rule it out)

Comment: No need to re-install, a "repair" will work fine and preserve data/applications.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the wrong drivers. Your Windows installation has adapted itself to your previous motherboard and has drivers set up for your harddrive controllers, chipsets, etc and you just tried to boot up with something entirely different. Use the repair function from the cdrom or simply do a reinstall.

Comment: I agree. One of the worst things you can do to a Windows installation is change the chipset out from under it. Reinstall is the safest way to go about the upgrade. An alternate suggestion is to go in to Windows in Safe Mode and uninstall potential problematic drivers, but that is there is risk involved for sure.

My experience from activation standpoint is that it will let you log-in or display a message before restarting. I'm not saying that joshhunt above is incorrect, though. Windows could behave differently with activation with different versions.

Comment: Even if you would manage to get back into the windows installation, it will usually be unstable and more effort than it's worth. Easier to just throw everything into windows.old and reinstall.